# Get via App Store bar

Tags: support, bug, ios-app, mobile-web

Opening question on mobile web via Chrome on the iOS device shows a bar at the top of page:

> [image: read]

After tapping on it installed ios-app will be open. But after return to Chrome I see modified text in the bar:

> [image: get]

Should the text "Get via App Store" be displayed even if ios-app already installed?

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Answer (score 3):

For as far as I know you can't detect if the app has actually been installed on the device, so that message is necessary to give you the ability to go to the app store once you dismissed the download dialog you get.

The additional text gives you two distinct options: go to the app store or retry opening the post in the app.

Although a little confusing, I think it currently is the best option the developers of the app have.

---

Update: okay [there is sort of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526211/993547), buy it requires to show a very annoying banner on every page you open. I like the current design better...

Comment: The bug is that it *only* shows the "Get via App Store" *after* opening the post in the app, not before

Comment: Where is the bug? It should do that since that is 99% of the time the action you want to perform.

Comment: I don't see the logic there... it only shows *after* you open the app (or click the banner to get the app), why would you need the App Store link 99% of the time *after* you already have the app? The only time it kind of makes sense is the first time you ever click the link (to get the app), but in that case it should show the link *before*, not after. The entire logic is backwards

Comment: Sometimes loading the app fails for whatever reason: old version, expired beta, etc. Linking the app store is the best option available then.

Comment: But those are the exception, not the norm. If the problem is not being able to detect if the app is available then *always* show the link (having it only show up *after* is confusing).

Comment: (I'm sure you should be able to detect the app with some JS and a custom URL scheme though)

Comment: No, you don't want to confuse users with the download link all the time. Usability is key here.

Comment: If you have a better way to detect if the app is installed, go ahead. Answer the questions on SO regarding that subject.

Comment: But that's my point, it's more confusing to only show the link after clicking the banner since most users will already have the app at that point

Comment: I didn't say you have any control, I just referred to the numerous questions on SO how to overcome this limitation of iOS.

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO on how to get around this, yes (you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14751543/1990216) for example).